# Tool tip is not working while hover the profile name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-card

### Tool tip is not working while hovering the profile name

When I hover over the profile icon:

[image]

But when I hover the profile name near by the profile icon. it's does not work:

[image]

Also it's not working in meta either. You can check this in my name under this question.

Comment: So, is this a `[discussion]`, a `[bug]` report, or a request for `[support]`?

Comment: @Cerbrus request for not `[support]`  request for `[feature-request]`?

Comment: That's not even English. Instead of responding to my comment with some kind of clever reply, please update your question. And while you're at it, maybe crop the images in your question, to remove all the white space.

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. This is clearly not a discussion, so you either think this is not working as intended and thus a bug, or you think this is working as intended and want it to be changed, so it'd be a feature request.

Comment: Okay we will meet an another question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as on the main site, *"It's not working"* is unhelpful and off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

That's working as intended.
The hover is only shown when you hover over the profile image.

Comment: What about this question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358926/popup-does-not-showing-while-hover-the-profile-icon-in-activity-tab the tooltip also not working while hover the profile icon?

Answer (score 5):

The 'fly out' user-card is only supposed to activate when you hover over the user's avatar, *on* their user-card, which is presented on each post that they write.

If we made it hover on their user name, then we'd effectively be blocking the link to their profile page, which wouldn't be a very smart thing to do :)